# Hosting of an EventProcessorHost in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

In an IoT Scenario, I have many messages streaming into an EventHub. I need an EventProcessorHost to do operation on the messages and for further processing.

How can I host an EventProcessotHost in Azure?
I do not have Kubernetes or ServiceFabric at the moment I don't want to have in the future. What other possibility do I have that also scale?

Comment: What about just using Azure Functions for this? Or do you have a specific reason not to use them?

Answer (score 0):

What about using [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/)? They support [Azure Event Hub Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs).

> **Trigger**
>   Use the function trigger to respond to an event sent to an event hub event stream. You must have read access to the underlying event hub to set up the trigger. When the function is triggered, the message passed to the function is typed as a string.
>
> **Trigger - Scaling**
>   Each instance of an event triggered function is backed by a single EventProcessorHost instance. The trigger (powered by Event Hubs) ensures that only one EventProcessorHost instance can get a lease on a given partition.

Comment: Good point. I will check costs and scalability for 10 000 of messages  per second. What could be a problem is that the function should connect to a mqtt broker and publish data to it.